# Can not load rss in SharePoint 2013 project

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, xml, rss

I have webpart which render the last news from rss channel with url: http://habrahabr.ru/rss/company/my_company/blog. I use:

```
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(urlToBlogThroughtRss);
            var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item");
```

Where urlToBlogThroughtRss is the url above. Yesterday all was fine but today I have exception:

> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to authentication results.

When I tried to do some steps in simple console project I have not proplems.

What was happend?